# Qt C++ How to create a global dynamic Object?

Tags: c++, qt, class, dynamic, global

This problem has been bothering me for 2 days, I don't know how to implement it, thanks in advance

I Have defined 3 class Equipment, Equipment1 and Equipment2. Equipment is the base class and the 3 classes has one same function name void eloadqdebug(), but the function content are different.

Below are the three classes.

```
class Equipment1 : public Equipment
{
public:
    Equipment1 ();
    void eloadqdebug(){qDebug()<<"message from Equipment1";};
};

class Equipment2 : public Equipment
{
public:
    Equipment2 ();
    void eloadqdebug(){qDebug()<<"message from Equipment2";};
};

class Equipment : public QMainWindow
{
        Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Equipment (QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    virtual void eloadqdebug(){qDebug()<<"message from base Equipment";};
};
```

In mainpanel i want to define a global class variable(currentequipment). I need Global because I have different pushbutton and Qtimer task.

I have tried `Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(Equipment, currentequipment);`

Below are the pushbutton Code:

```
void MainPanel::on_pushButton_equipment_selected_clicked()
{
    QString Equipment_from_comboBox=ui->comboBox_Equipment->currentText();// the selected text from comboBox
    if (Equipment_from_comboBox=="Equipment1"){
        Equipment* currentequipment=new Equipment1();
        currentequipment->eloadqdebug();
    }
    else if (Equipment_from_comboBox=="Equipment2"){
        Equipment* currentequipment=new Equipment2();
        currentequipment->eloadqdebug();
    }

}
```

Here is the Task Qtimer every 1s

```
void MainPanel::timer1000msTask()// implement every 1s
{

      currentequipment->eloadqdebug();
 
}
```

The this image is my result. I run the Qt and Equipment1 from comboBox is selected. I click the pushbutton after about 2s. But after it Qtimer still use class Equipment ratehr than Equipment1 to define the object variable(currentequipment). I want currentequipment is always class Equipment1 after clicking the Pushbutton.

[image]

My goal is to make the object variable(currentequipment) to be Equipment1 when I select Equipment1 in comboBox and make the object variable(currentequipment) to be Equipment2 when I select Equipment2 in comboBox.

It would be great if you could give me an idea in this or another direction to solve the global dynamic Object problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on the description, there's nothing obviously wrong with the shown code, therefore the problem must be in code that's not shown. It's obvious that this is not the real code, but ad-hoc code that you believe accurately represents the real code, but it's not. Since noone on Stackoverflow has access to real code, it's unlikely that anyone will figure out the problem in code that's not shown. But, as the first step, you should add an `override` qualifier to virtual methods that you believe should override the one in the base class, and then see if your compiler agrees with you.

Comment: hello sam, 

Thank you.

Is it possible that this code restricts currentequipment to class Equipment

**Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(Equipment, currentequipment);**

Comment: What is your understanding of what Q_GLOBAL_STATIC does, do you know what it does? If you do, how does that work with the shown logic in `on_pushButton_equipment_selected_clicked`, which creates a new instance every time? And then leaks the memory? It is not likely that anyone can give you useful advise based on isolated code snippets that fail Stackoverflow's requirements for a [mre].

Comment: The reason for this output is that you actually create a **local** variable each time in `on_pushButton_equipment_selected_clicked()` and you **do not reassign** the global variable. If you remove `Equipment*` from `Equipment* currentequipment=new Equipment1();` you code may start to work. I write may because I am not sure about how exactly that Q_GLOBAL_STATIC macro works... But still this code will be a disaster because you are leaking memory.

Comment: ... addendum to the previous comment: you can avoid memory leaks if you forget about `Q_GLOBAL_STATIC` and use good old `std::unique_ptr`. Then reassigning the old object with new object will also automatically destroy the old object. I recomments that you add destructor to your `Equipment` class which will log each destruction to console. This way you can check that the object are destroyed correctly once reassigned.

Comment: hello HiFile,  Ihave tried to remove Equipment* and I get the error No viable overloaded. '='. 
I will try the  std::unique_ptr. Sorry i am not good at qt and c++

Comment: Yeah, I suspected, that Q_GLOBAL_STATIC may block re-assignment. But unique_ptr should work. Use `currentequipment = std::make_unique< Equipment1 >();` to reaassign.